# Problema con render en Django multitenant

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Tengo un proyecto llamado ripso_v2 en python3 y django 1.9 que por ahora tiene un par de apps (creadas con el startapp y al cual agregué el archivo urls.py y forms.py) llamadas "general" y "phva", la carpeta principal del proyecto y una carpeta para los templates.

#### phva / urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from phva.views import planear

app_name = 'phva'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^inicio$', planear.inicio, name='phva_inicio'),
    url(r'^planear$', planear.planear, name='phva_planear'),
]
```

#### ripso_v2 / urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # solo en servidor de desarrollo

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='publico/index.html'), name='home'),

    url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name':'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page':'login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^cambiar-pass/$', views.password_change, {'template_name':'cambiar-pass.html', 'post_change_redirect':'login'}, name='cambiar_pass'),

    url(r'^general/', include('general.urls')),
    url(r'^perticular/', include('phva.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Tuve que actualizar a `a href="{% url 'phva:phva_inicio' %}"` dado que es algo de django 1.9

## Error

[image: parte1]
[image: parte2]
[image: parte3]

#### phva / views / planear.py

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, render_to_response, get_list_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from phva.forms import *

from ripso_v2.utilities import *

@login_required
def inicio(request):
    return render(request, 'phva_inicio.html')

@login_required
def planear(request):
    return render(request, 'phva_planear.html')
```

Comment: No veo que las URLs de tu app `particular` las estés incluyendo en `ripso_v2 / urls.py`

Comment: puse "Problema con urls" porque aparentemente no está leyendo líneas como url(r'^inicio$', planear.inicio, name='acc_inicio'),

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si lo cambias a `<a href="{% url 'particular:acc_inicio' %}">`?,  ¿te sale el mismo error?

Comment: Al parecer las cosas han cambiado un poco en Django 1.9 con respecto a las apps y las URLs, yo todavía no pruebo Django 1.9 por eso no puedo ayudarte del todo. Por cierto, el `render` no ha cambiado, actualiza e incluye el error

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez tienes el stack trace del error nuevo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta no es una respuesta definitiva a tu problema ya que te has topado con un problema nuevo, sin embargo, considero que esto no se vería bien como un comentario y ayuda a entender tu problema inicial con respecto a las URLs.

Según las [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/) de Django 1.9 con respecto a las [URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#urls):

> The application namespace can now be set using an app_name attribute on the included module or object. It can also be set by passing a 2-tuple of (, ) as the first argument to include().

Es decir, que definiendo el `app_name` en el `urls.py` de tu app, ya estás definiendo el `namespace`:

```
app_name = 'particular'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^inicio$', planear.inicio, name='acc_inicio'),
    url(r'^planear$', planear.planear, name='acc_planear'),
]
```

Esto quiere decir que al usar el tag `url` en tu template necesitas pasarle también el `namespace`:

```
<a href="{% url 'particular:acc_inicio' %}">Inicio</a>
```

De lo contrario, Django te mostrará el error `NoReverseMatch` de tu pregunta original al no encontrar el patrón.

También es posible usar la forma anterior usando el parámetro `namespace` en la llamada a la función `include`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^particular/', include('particular.urls', namespace='particular')),
    # ...
]
```

Ambos métodos son válidos.

### Nota:

Incluye el nuevo error para dar con la solución

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta, necesitas saber algo más?, si el archivo phva_inicio.html lo dejo vacio o con sólo texto, no muestra el error... no me deja poner el {% extends 'base.html' %}

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez ok, la reviso

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez creo que te falta incluir el archivo `phva/urls.py` en tu pregunta

Comment: es el particular / urls.py ... sólo había cambiado la palabra phva por particular por efectos de la pregunta pero mejor lo dejo tal cual

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez ¿estás usando `{% url 'phva:phva_planear' %}` con el nombre del namespace?, en el traceback solo sale `phva_planear`

Comment: sí, por eso digo que no me da error si el archivo phva_inicio.html está vacío o con un hola mundo, pero con sólo poner el  {% extends 'base.html' %} ya aparece el error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35244/discussion-between-diana-carolina-hernandez-and-cesar).

Comment: Cambié a Django 1.8 y no hubo problema